# Integrate Angular 5 in Asp.net core 1.0

Tags: angular5, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to integrate asp.net core web applicaion with the angular 5. But not able to find the correct procedure or way to do.

I have followed various links, but no use like getting the errors.

Also I tried to work with installing the templates with angular and core but throws error. I think might be the version error, as its angular 2 template integrated with the .net core 1.0.

Please let me the solution or the way to integrate through links or your idea of approching.

Comment: What kind issues are you facing?

Comment: Also are you trying to integrate Angular into existing app or  create from scratch?

Comment: Try with this link http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: @OlegI, Thanks for your response. My actual requirement is to integrate with existing one, but first for demo I am working from scratch.

Comment: @NitinAgarwal, The link is related to angular2 which already I preferred, and I am in search of Angular 5. Its giving me the error in dependency of node modules and bla bla bla.....

Comment: @NitinAgarwal, I have tried with the link, but get the error as 500 internal server error, multiple overload of method 'Configure' is not supported

Comment: @NitinAgarwal, I have tried with the link and solved the issue of that error, but there is no process of installing the angular application through cli or manually. They have copied that project, if any more help will be great.